# Why are r-value objects allowed to be modified by the compiler?

Tags: c++, rvalue

In the following code, `A(100)` is a temporary object or an r-value. The compiler did not throw an error when a member function tried to modify a member variable. Are r-values read-only?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
  int i;
public:
  A() {cout << "In default ctor\n";};
  A(int v) {cout << "Setting i in par-ctor to " << v << "\n"; i=v;}
  void print() {cout << "i = " << i << endl;}
  void seti(int val){i=val;print();}
};

int main()
{
  A(100).seti(200);

  return(0);
}
```

Also, if it is required to use `const` in copy constructors to ensure rvalues are not modified, why is it not the same case here?

Comment: `Are not r-values read-only?` who said that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any requirement for rvalues to be read only. The opposite is true, modifications can be made, but the changes to that object will be as short lived as the temporary object itself (its lifetime being possibly being extended with an appropriate reference).

A copy constructor does not have to take its argument as `const&`, it can just be by a non-cv reference as well (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor).

> A copy constructor of class T is a non-template constructor whose first parameter is T&, const T&, volatile T&, or const volatile T&

In general, they do take their argument as `const&` and this will allow temporary objects to be used during copy construction.

Answer (score 3):

Simple: Yes you are creating a temporary object and yes it's an rvalue. But rvalues are not read-only :)